# Неверная работа хлебных крошек на Bitrix

Tags: битрикс, breadcrumbs

Хлебные крошки на Битрикс неверно работают в карточке товара — выводят все инфоблоки. Выглядит это примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно что-то вроде "Главная/Каталог/Автономные отопители/Планар/Модель отопителя", но я понятия не имею, как это сделать

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что в карточке товара я выводил блок сопутствующих товаров, компонентом bitrix:catalog.element. После того как я прописал ему "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "N", "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N" все стало работать нормально.